# what is the meaning of "duly attached" in?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "duly attached" in the sentence from Sherlock Holmes novel "A Study in Scarlet"?

> "I was *duly attached* to the Fifth Northumberland Fusiliers as Assistant Surgeon".

Does "duly" mean "properly" or "as expected"? Also does "being attached" mean "designated"?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+duly

Comment: In this sentence, does "duly" mean "properly" or "as expected"? Also does "being attached" mean "designated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, in this case (and time period), the meaning is "as expected," or "as events took their normal course."   The "attached" part does mean "assigned to" or equivalently "ordered to join...".

Answer (score 2):

*Duly attached* just means he was a part of the regiment per his orders.

A surgeon wouldn't typically be a regular combat soldier in the regiment, so he would be attached meaning that he followed the regiment as their medic.   In this sense, attached means assigned for special duties.

Comment: The word *fighter*, is strange and awkward in this context. That's normally a word for a category of combat aircraft http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fighter_aircraft. A way of saying it that would be more suitable, would be *combatant* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/combatant?q=combatant or *combat soldier*.

Comment: @Tristanr [Fighter](http://i.word.com/idictionary/fighter) one who fights, warrior, etc. It's perfectly apt. Fighter to mean plane is the secondary meaning of the word, and was derived from that usage.

Comment: It doesn't sound very appropriate for a professional, military person. It just covers anyone who fights in general, without referring to military personnel in particular, which this question is about.

Comment: @tristanr First, I'm describing the function of a type of soldier. Second, soldier is the FIRST synonym in the definition.

Comment: David M, I realise that. *Fighter* just seems too vague and unprofessional for this question, which has a military and army context in particular.

Comment: @Tristanr There.  I've changed it.

Comment: Oh, that's surprising.

Comment: @Tristanr Well, it seemed to be a sticking point for you.  And, it didn't harm the meaning of the answer in either case.